# How to make an OnEdit() script that re-sorts my data by 3 columns as I complete the entry for a row?

Tags: excel, sorting, google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting

I'm looking for an OnEdit() script that re-sorts my data by 3 columns as I complete the entry for a row.

Here's an example of a [Raw example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-9Oy1aDZwvuEreZ1eXjJ7h2Yx2QD3NU7BoIHAttKJ7c/edit?usp=sharing) of the kind of spreadsheets I'm putting together, and another example of what I'd love to see as a [Processed example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19LYzEPMSF0UiHvw8tpRDWZ7cmZNfsBKF6EPqytR0Jrs/edit?usp=sharing) -- that is, roughly how I'd like the script sheets to group and sort the sheets in the following order:

-*FIRST SORTIN*G: **Column A** -> Agency [sort A - Z] -- so that all Agency rows are groups together, and sorted A - Z

-Then, *SECOND SORTING*: **Column B** -> Sub-Agency [sort A - Z] -- so that all Sub-Agency rows are groups together, and sorted A - Z

-And finally, *THIRD SORTING*: **Column C** -> Date: Sent or Received [sort Z - A] -- so that after the Agency rows are grouped and sorted, and Sub-Agency rows are grouped and sorted, the rows can be sorted by "Date: Sent or Received" values, starting with the earliest date at the bottom

Also, *if possible*, I'd create a row, or some kind of definition, between every new value entered in one of my columns. Specifically, I'd like there to be some kind of row space / definition between every new Sub-Agency, which are values that I enter in Column B of my spreadsheet.

Any ideas / suggestion on how do this?

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I see the other question you did and seems identical. Try to edit question to improve them instead of creating new ones.

Nevertheless I made a very sample script to show you a way to order by row in a custom way.

```js
function onEdit(e) {
    const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    const targetRange = sheet.getRange("A2:C8" );

    let data = targetRange.getValues();

    Logger.log(data)

    data.sort((a, b) => {
        if (a[0] == b[0] && a[1] == b[1] && a[2] == b[2]) {
            return 0; // Same row 
        }
        if (a[0] == b[0] && a[1] == b[1]) { // Third column is different
            return a[2] < b[2] ? 1 : -1;

        }
        if (a[0] == b[0]) { // Second column is different
            return a[1] > b[1] ? 1 : -1;

        }

        return a[0] > b[0] ? 1 : -1; // Reaching this point first column is differen
    })
    Logger.log(data);
    targetRange.setValues(data);
}
```

The idea is simple, gather all the values and then decide what criteria you want to implement to determine which should come first.

If you still don't understand what is happening here take a look at the documentation for [`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort). In special on how does the `compareFunction` do.

#### Result

Starting with this data:

[image: First]

After the `onEdit` trigger kicks in:

[image: After]

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I hear you re: my previous post, but it's actually different because it's framed around an OnEdit() sorting script. Anyway, thx so much for laying this out. I've only copied/pasted scripts; never done them. Quick questions... Does your script sort Columns A & B [A - Z], and then Column C (date) [Z - A] -- so that dates go from oldest at the bottom to newest on top? And is there any way to create  spacial definition (e.g., blank row) between the grouped values in Columns A & B? Many thanks again!

Comment: BTW, I think I understand what you mean about editing questions instead adding new ones. Point taken. Still getting used to the approach to forum protocol in StackOverflow. Thanks.

Comment: Yes the script sorts A and B in an ascending order and C descending. For me the way you want to create a spacial definition seems like an other question. It would be easier to create  another post and get responded there. It shouldn't be very difficult though, remember to include the expected output and a sample sheet with an example of how your data is and how you want it to end.

Comment: Wonderful. Thank you so much! I *greatly* appreciate your help with all of this... Two quick question: (1) I've shifted my dates from Column C to Column D. How can I tweak the script to reflect this change? and (2) How / when does the script initiate? Does it work after I've filled out values on the row or just moved onto another row? Thanks!

Comment: Anyway, after I hear back from you I'll first try to include your script into my spreadsheet, and will circle back if I have any questions or problems.  Once I feel like it's up and running properly, I'll post another, separate query re: the spacial separation. FWIW, the  [Processed example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19LYzEPMSF0UiHvw8tpRDWZ7cmZNfsBKF6EPqytR0Jrs/edit?usp=sharing) represents exactly what I'm seeking in that regard. Thanks so much again!

Comment: The number of the columns are the position in the array in the `sort` implementation. So think `a[0]` `b[0]` refers to the first column of the two rows being compared. In the code just change the column `C` to column `D` by changing `a[2]` `b[2]` to `a[3]` `b[3]`. Also you need to modify the range at the start of the code to adapt it to your actual problem, you can just put `A2:H`. 
If the function name is `onEdit` it will run every time you modify your sheet so it will be kept updated.

Comment: Thank you so much! I think I follow what you mean. I'll give it a whirl to see if I can make those changes work. Thank you again for all of your help - I really do appreciate it...